# OctoberCMS plugin record update server internal error

Tags: laravel, octobercms

Internal Server error on update record with hasOne relation field in builder tool of octoberCMS

Comment: Show your code? so we can help you ?

Comment: please post the code from the controller that you are trying to update also the models relationship

Comment: 'public $belongsTo = [
        "parent_id" => [
            "Stuff\Profession\Models\Profession_list",
            "table" => "stuff_profession_list",
            "key"=>"parent_id"
        ]
    ];'

Comment: This is the relation i have user in the model

Comment: controller is auto generated from builder pluigin

Comment: from that I can tell you that you need to define both keys and becaouse it is a belongsTo then you can try to define it like this  'user' => ['Acme\Blog\Models\User', 'key' => 'my_user_id', 'otherKey' => 'my_id'

Answer (score 0):

In my database parent_id is foreign key and i have use same name for label too for the relation, so i have change label from parent_id to parent, what i understand it cause infinite recursion of query because of same name of label and foreign key "parent_id" which cause server error 500,
it have resolve my issue

```
public $belongsTo = [ "parent_id" => 
[ 
"Stuff\Profession\Models\Profession_list", 
"table" => "stuff_profession_list", "key"=>"parent_id" ] 
];
```

to

```
public $belongsTo = [ "parent" => [ "Stuff\Profession\Models\Profession_list", "table" => "stuff_profession_list", "key"=>"parent_id" ] ];
```